# Why TypeScript type guard not narrowing down the union?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

In the following TypeScript code, I expect `contact` to be narrowed down to `GroupContact` due to the type guard in place, but `contact` is still `Contact | GroupContact`. Why?

```js
type Contact = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    contactInfo: {
        isStarred: boolean;
    }
}

type GroupContact = Omit<Contact, "contactInfo">;

function isGroupContact(contact: Contact | GroupContact): contact is GroupContact {
    return !("contactInfo" in contact);
}

function foo(contact: Contact | GroupContact) {
    if (isGroupContact(contact)) {
        console.log("group", contact); // why contact is `Contact | GroupContact` here and not `GroupContact`?
    } else {
        console.log("not group", contact);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because TypeScript uses [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system). Consider this example from [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#structural-typing):

> ```ts
> let o = { x: "hi", extra: 1 }; // ok
> let o2: { x: string } = o; // ok
> ```
>
> Here, the object literal `{ x: "hi", extra: 1 }` has a matching literal type `{ x: string, extra: number }`. That type is assignable to `{ x: string }` since it has all the required properties and those properties have assignable types. The extra property doesn’t prevent assignment, it just makes it a subtype of `{ x: string }`.

The compiler is operating the same way on the code you showed as it does in the example: the derived type `GroupContact` looks like this when expanded:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwMbCgXigbwFACQAlgCYBcUAzsAE5EIDmA3IQsgLYQXV2MsGpEKdAEkEAMzgUcUIpQDKKGjQjkoAIzhwANhGQIoAXxbG8eUJCgBxGnACuYeEjQZsAeXZFgAHifDgADRQAESCzqIScMEAfCwA9HFQSQB6APx4QA)

```ts
type GroupContact = Omit<Contact, "contactInfo">;
/*   ^?
type GroupContact = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
*/
```

The `GroupContact` type doesn't restrict a property `contactInfo` from being present — it just means that the type must have the properties `id` and `name` of type `string` — which means that any value of type `Contact` is also assignable to `GroupContact`, so the type guard doesn't actually narrow.

To indicate that the type "must not have a defined value at the property `contactInfo`", you can use an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) of type [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#never):

```ts
type GroupContact = Omit<Contact, "contactInfo"> & { contactInfo?: never };
```

…and narrowing will work as expected:

```ts
function foo(contact: Contact | GroupContact) {
  if (isGroupContact(contact)) {
    console.log("group", contact);
    //                   ^? (parameter) contact: GroupContact
  } else {
    console.log("not group", contact);
    //                       ^? (parameter) contact: Contact
  }
}
```

[Code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwMbCgXigbwFACQAlgCYBcUAzsAE5EIDmA3IQsgLYQXV2MsGpEKdAEkEAMzgUcUIpQDKKGjQjkoAIzhwANhGQIoAXxbG8eUJCgBxGnACuYeEjQZsAeXZFgAHifDgADRQAESCzqIScMEAfFAAZLhQYf5ikgD8FAgQAG4QNEYseOJ2COhEiLKUNvaOQi4AFITJLhR+LlAAPta2Dm3oAXgAlBTN6JXdNX0Y+AQqwHY0BgCE9aF1EZLBsgajwIMmZsWlwOUGknD1u63rGF3VvTeDuIRE4lD1cve14cCXj08zASISg6CAAOm0cAYqwYPTAwSCu32hAIAHpUVBMVjsTjsQA9NKEQxQCDaSjQQFhEG6CFQ1YIOAYWE1BFJR78NEY3HcnlQAlEvCGPBAA)

---

See also: [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes)